# I couldn't understand how to make a k-fold cross validation test with multi-class SVM

Tags: matlab, validation, svm, cross-validation

i am very new to matlab and SVM and i am reproducing this experiment from strach http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/19/13/1656.full.pdf

*There they say "In the training of SVMs, we use the method of one versus
the others, or one versus the rest" . ok there are 12 classes so they produce 12 SVMs. they train each one with positives vs all rest.

*but then they say "The prediction performance was examined by the 5-fold cross-validation test"

My noob question is, How can they make a k-fold cross validation after! they train SVMs. what i think(likely faulty) is when you make a k-fold cross validation, you construct a new svm from beginning. they may be similar but svm model is different in every loop. there are k different svm models. but, if they train svm models beforehand, How can they make a cross validation test? What am i missing? Please help and thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First they produce cross-validated datasets. Then they train 5 models (one for each fold) and repeatedly train-test. You can do this as follows:

```
% I assume use of LIBSVM for svm training-testing in this code snippet
% Create a random data
data=1+2*randn(1000,10);
labels=randi(12,[1000,1]);

%do 5-fold cross-validation
ind=crossvalind('Kfold',labels,5);

for i=1:5
    % (4/5)^th random data for training
    trainingData=data(ind~=5,:); %notice ~=
    trainingLabels=labels(ind~=5); 

    % (1/5)^th random data for testing
    testingData=data(ind==5,:); %notice ==
    testingLabels=labels(ind==5); 

   % train svm
    model{i,1}=svmtrain(trainingLabels,trainingData);

   %test svm
   [predLabels{i,1},accuracy(i,1)]=svmpredict(testingLabels,testingData,model{i,1});
end

% I think this is what they mean when they say, we analyze the performance
% using 5 -fold cross validation

% following two things is what you will report
plot(accuracy);  %how accuracy varies over random selection of data
avgAccuracy=mean(accuracy); %what is the average accuracy over 5 runs?
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. So do they train two different sets of svm's, one for reporting accuracy and one for actually performing analyses? because they say "In the training of SVMs, we use the method of one versus the others, or one versus the rest" that svm set must be different than the svm models in loop for reporting accuracy. or is it actually the same thing? may that mean, using k-fold validation also employs one vs rest strategy?

Comment: One vs rest is different than k-fold validation. One vs. rest is the technique of training muli-class svm. That technique is implemented *inside* `svmtrain`.  So to answer your question, <<So do they train two different sets of svm's, one for reporting accuracy and one for actually performing analyses?>>, answer is no. The loop is to "train and test" svm on different data. To make sure that you have not over-fitted your SVM i.e. it doesn't give good output only on one set of data.